# Eliminate duplicate code introduced by Func and Action

Tags: c#, action, func

There is a generic function with a return type.

```
TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<string, TResult> callback)
{
    string message = Generate_some_string();
    return callback(message);
}
```

And also there is a similar one without a return type since there is no Func.

```
void Invoke(Action<string> callback)
{
    string message = Generate_some_string();
    callback(message);
}
```

But these are duplicate code. Once Invoke changes, Invoke has to be changed correspondingly. Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate code?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: What changes are you thinking of? Probably all changes should be done within `Generate_some_string`, so these "wrapper"-methods would remain unchanged. Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
void Invoke(Action<string> callback)
{
    Invoke<int>(s=>{callback(s);return 0;});
}
```

That way all your logic stays in the `Func` version and your `Action` version should never have to change.

Another option would be to create a `ToFunc` conversion routine, and place the onus on your callers to change their action into a func:

```
public static Func<TIn, TResult> ToFunc<TIn, TResult>(this Action<TIn> a)
{
    return input =>
    {
        a(input);
        return default(TResult);
    };
}
```